# How capture and stop propagation of all taps in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my app, I want to render the whole app but if the user is not logged in then I want to pop up the modal bottom sheet to prompt them to log in if they tap on anything on the screen.

I was hoping to be able to wrap the whole screen with a `GestureDetector` but it seems that the nested buttons get the tap events first.

I was hoping I could use a `Listener` and then cancel (stop propagation/bubbling) the event on PointerUp but this doesn't appear to be possible.

I was hoping to be able to overlap a *transparent* `Container` to capture all taps if the user is not logged in but I am not sure if this is possible either.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Flutter without having to add code to check for logged-in user on each nested widget's onTap handler?

Comment: what about `AbsorbPointer` / `IgnorePointer` widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the pointer @pskink - this solved the problem for me:

```
class LoginHandlerWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool absorbPointer =
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.isAnonymous == true;

  LoginHandlerWrapper({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Listener(
        onPointerDown: (event) {
          if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.isAnonymous == true) {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context, builder: (context) => const SignIn());
          }
        },
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          absorbing: absorbPointer,
          child: child,
        ));
  }
}
```